# CSS display:table not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-tables

Can someone please help me figure out why this is not working in Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/cZQUb/6/

```
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
html, body{height:100%;width:100%;}

.mainNav{display:block;height:100px;width:100%;}

.mainContainer{display:table;background:#666;height:calc(100% - 100px);width:100%;}
.sideNav{display:table-cell;background:#888;height:100%;min-width:300px;}
.rightContResp{display:table-cell;background:#333;height:calc(100% - 50px);width:100%;}

.filters{display:table-row;width:100%;height:50px;}

.rightCont{display:table;width:100%;height:100%;}
.messegersContResp{display:table-cell;background:#999;height:100%;min-width:300px;}
.messegersCont{display:block;height:100%;width:100%;overflow:auto;}
.messegersCont div{display:block;height:150px;width:100%;border-bottom:1px solid grey;}

.messageContResp{display:table-cell;background:#333;height:100%;width:100%;}
.messageCont{display:table;width:100%;height:100%;position:relative;}

.messageHead{display:block;min-height:100px;width:100%;background:purple;position:absolute;top:0px;}
.messageContent{display:block;height:calc(100% - 100px);width:100%;background:blue;position:absolute;top:100px;overflow:auto;box-sizing:border-  box;padding-top:5px;}
.messageContent div{height:200px;width:175px;margin-right:10px;background:black;display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: What is the reasoning in using display: table?

Comment: @sheriffderek This was the only way I could consider getting this type of layout to work and be responsive

Comment: I don't see how it's responsive except for maybe the grid area changes size a bit.

Comment: Your rightI actually got it working without using tables.... just floats and width: calc();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it to work properly, you'll need to rework it so all of the table's immediate children are table-rows, and all of the table-rows' immediate children are table-cells.